# What is the NodeJS equivalent code for Http post as in Java

Tags: java, node.js, express, http-post

I'm currently trying to convert a java project to Node.js(with Express.js) project.

Here is a request which works well in java, the response status code is 200 ok

```
HttpPost postFormRequest = new HttpPost(host + "/auth/j_security_check");
List<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", rtcLogin));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", rtcPassword));
postFormRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse postFormResponse = null;
postFormResponse = client.execute(postFormRequest);
```

Now when I do the same in Node.js with this:

```
const host = 'https://host.com/ccm';
const rtcAuthPath = '/auth/j_security_check';
const credentials = { j_username: 'login', j_password: '********' };
const authOptions = {
   url: host + rtcAuthPath,
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
};

function auth(error, response, body){
    log(response);
}

request.post(authOptions, auth);
```

With this code above I'm getting `302 Found`

The only difference I see is the form encoding in java:

```
postFormRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
```

So what is the equivalence of this in Node.js ?

Comment: Js sweet looks good for you http://www.jsweet.org/

Comment: 302 means url redirection. It seems that your server redirects you and there is no problem in your client code

Comment: You need to just follow the redirect, so find a library that can do that or read the 302 location and send the request again to that target

Comment: The problem is the URL form encoding of parameters, the 302 redirect is just a consequence of a failed login which redirects to the error login page (probably). You can try packages like this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-urlencoded

Comment: Note that this isn't really a question about Node.js, but about the `request` library. `request` has the options `followRedirect` and `followAllRedirects` -- see the documentation. But if you authenticate properly, you shouldn't get redirected.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter since you're moving away from Java, but you shouldn't pass in "UTF-8" as a String since it can throw `UnsupportedEncodingException`. You can `import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;` and then write `new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, UTF_8)`.

Comment: Sorry, but it just annoys me to still see code that is using strings for encodings. StandardCharsets was added in Java 7 in 2011.